# Scrolling UITableView detects TouchDown but not TouchUpInside on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uibutton

- I have a UITableView with custom cells
- Each cell has a button
- The button has two IBActions: 1 on TouchDown and 1 on TouchUpInside
- While in mid scroll (when the tableview has been scrolled and maintains scroll momentum) the button detects touchdown, but not touchup

How can I detect an event equivalent to touchup or disable touchdown when scrolling is occurring?

Comment: Not sure what is what you want to achieve, touch down is detected becouse you did touch down to scroll, but TouchUpInside is an event that is not intended to be detected when you do this. you want to detect an event on the cell or not?

Comment: I want to have a button event press/release pair that is consistent when scrolling.

Comment: Touch up is when you release the touch on the button - is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. When the button is touched (touchdown) I want to run code and when it is released (touchup...) I want to run different code. I want the two events to be consistent when in mid scroll. touchdown registers while scrolling and touchupinside does not.